# How to draw in rect with bezier path?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, drawing, uibezierpath, cgrect

I have a some rect in my view and I want to draw a figure in that rect with UIBezierPath.

I thought that method

```
UIBezierPath myBezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:myRect];
```

will make an empty UIBezierPath called myBezierPath, with bounds that myRect gives to it, and then I can "draw" it that myBezierPath using moveToPoint and addLineToPoint. But, that code made a square (I'm stroke that path, so stroked square) with bounds that was in myRect.
But I don't want him to be visible. I only want that if I try this:

```
NSLog(@"myBezierPath rect size %f,%f",myBezierPath.bounds.size.width,myBezierPath.bounds.size.height);
```

It returns me the width and height that myRect has.
And therefore I can use it in my moveToPoint method and addLine method. For example like this:

```
[myBezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(suit.bounds.size.width/2, 0)];
```

Thanks.

**My question is: «How can I draw in rect using bezier path?»**

I made this with method, here myRect have origin that place CGRect with myBezierPath in center of the view.

```
myBezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:myRect cornerRadius:20.0];
```

[Example 1 http://i.minus.com/iguFjeqZQrsb6.png](http://i.minus.com/iguFjeqZQrsb6.png)

How can I made similar (place my another drawing to center with origin)?
Now I have this:

[Example 2 http://i.minus.com/ifVY9UAP7hVv3.png](http://i.minus.com/ifVY9UAP7hVv3.png)

Comment: What's the question? You've already solved the problem. To construct a path, construct it; don't use `bezierPathWithRect`, since that constructs a rectangular path which isn't what you want.

Comment: There's no actual question here. All it says is that you thought something and discovered (rightly) that you were wrong. (Reading the docs would have prevented that.) That's great but there's no question.

Comment: @matt my question is how I can do what I want, if you don't understood that. I can't find a way in docs and internet. I update my question.

Comment: Make an empty bezier path with `+bezierPath`. Now draw using the bezier path using `moveToPoint` and `addLineToPoint` exactly as you said, and make sure that your drawing stays within the rect! Really, I still don't see the problem.

Comment: hmmm okay, if i just make this `myBezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];` I'll draw in my view with origin(0,0), but I need to draw in some rect with origin(24,192) for example. How?

Comment: you need to override drawRect method in your class, and class must be subclass of UIView then and only then you can draw it

Comment: @DipenPanchasara i made this already.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara reread my question please, and watch the screens.

Comment: @matt check the screenshots I post in question please.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking but I feel like maybe [my post about Bézier paths](http://ronnqvi.st/thinking-like-a-bzier-path/) will help you with UIBezierPath.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I just can't figure out how to "move" my drawing from the corner to the center. With method  `bezierPathWithRoundedRect:` this is so easy to understood, but without it I can't find a way. Where is the origin of this bezier path that i draw? Thanks for link I  will read right now.

Comment: @flinth dude you have to use arithmetic to figure out where the path needs to go

Comment: Or you could use `applyTransform:` to shift the path over to the center.

Comment: @matt I know where the center is, i already use arithmetic)) How to said to my bezier path: "Hey you go to origin.x = ... and origin.y =..."??

Comment: I just told you that; either start with `moveToPoint` at the correct origin, or start at zero and shift the origin with `applyTransform:`

Comment: @matt hmm that's strange, I thought there is some easier way to wrap my drawing to rect and then specify origin of that rect, but thanks for the `applyTransform` that's already something.

Comment: `applyTransform` *is* the way to draw in a rect and then change the origin. The normal way is to think first and work out the origin in advance and start there. See my code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example (you will need a UIImageView in your interface):

```
CGRect r = self.myImageView.bounds;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(r.size, NO, 0);
UIBezierPath* p = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectInset(r,10,10) cornerRadius:10];
[p stroke];
CGPoint c = CGPointMake(r.size.width/2.0, r.size.height/2.0);
p = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[p moveToPoint:CGPointMake(c.x-30, c.y)];
[p addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(c.x, c.y-30)];
[p addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(c.x+30, c.y)];
[p addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(c.x, c.y+30)];
[p closePath];
[p fill];
self.myImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

[image]

Comment: I made what I want, now I see why you can't understood my question :). There is no way to do this as i thought at all, but i was sure it is. I made it just add to `CGPointMake()` my calculated origin. Thanks matt.